# dd command create different file size

Tags: linux, python-3.x, shell

I'm running the following python script:

```
import os
   for i in range(1, 250):
       os.system("dd if=/home/user/file.txt of=/home/user/file%d.txt status=progress" %(i))
```

by executing the "ls -lh" command there are files with a smaller size than the original file.
example:

```
file1.txt 7.4MB --> Correct size
file2.txt 3.4MB --> Wrong size
file3.txt 7.4MB --> Correct size
file4.txt 7.4MB --> Correct size
file5.txt 2.5MB --> Wrong size
```

why are some files created with a smaller size?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try removing `status=progress` and see if that helps.

Comment: I expect this is because of the filesystem and not `dd` itself. Is the input file open for writing? Is it on the same mount point as the output file? Are either of them on a remote filesystem? Is this corrected if you run `sync` before checking the results?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Do you have a reason to think that will make a difference? It just controls the progress reporting, after all.

Comment: @l0b0 Nothing specific, but there must be some problem and it seems reasonable to try to isolate the cause by removing extraneous stuff till it goes away. One thought was that it may be producing so much output that a pipe or buffer somewhere gets full and blocks the progress of the `dd`. It probably won't make a difference but it seems the simplest piece of extraneous stuff to remove.

Comment: @l0b0 Yes, the file is in the same location as the output file. example: "/home/user/", Now trying to add the `sync` command after executing the `dd` command

Comment: @l0b0 With the `sync` command after the `dd` command there seems to be no problem. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to `sync` after such commands to wait for the data to be written to disk before trying to gauge its metadata.

Comment: Why the downvote? [OP did respond that it solved the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570455/dd-command-create-different-file-size/57578025#comment101614527_57570455).

Comment: the problem was solved by adding the "sync" command after each "dd".